# Javascript append only one of kind type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I should add to code bellow to:

- If there is more same hrefs inside .item a show only one input with it (in my case show only one input with value img/united-airlines.jpg and one with img/american-airlines.jpg)
- Place after the input how much that hrefs they are (in case bellow 2 img/united-airlines.jpg and 1 img/american-airlines.jpg)

Here is html:

```
<div class="wrap"> 
  <div class="item">
    <a href="img/american-airlines.jpg">
      American Airlines
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <a href="img/united-airlines.jpg">
      United Airlines
    </a>
  </div>
    <div class="item">
    <a href="img/united-airlines.jpg">
      United Airlines
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my script:

```
$(".wrap").find(".item a").each(function () {
  var xx = ( $(this).attr('href'));



  $("body").append('<label><input type="checkbox" value="' + xx +'">' + xx + '</label>');;
});
```

Codepen is here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RRwEvd?editors=1010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fixed pen: http://codepen.io/omerts/pen/YWzgjQ?editors=1010

```
$(".wrap").find(".item a").each(function () {
  var xx = ( $(this).attr('href'));

  if (!$('input[value="'+ xx +'"]').length) {
    $("body").append('<label><input type="checkbox" value="' + xx +'">' + xx + ' (<span>1</span>) </    label>'); 
  }  else {
    var currentCount = $('input[value="'+ xx +'"]').next('span')
    var newCount = parseInt(currentCount.text()) + 1
    currentCount.text(newCount)
  }
});
```